# iPhone: What are the differences between iPhone3GS and i pod touch 3rd as test device?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, ipod-touch

I think that all iPhone developers must support from iPhone3GS to iPhone4S if your target iOS version is iOS5.
Is that correct?

So I want to test with iPhone3GS.
But it is expensive.
So I bought `i pod touch 3rd` instead.

What are the differences between iPhone3GS and i pod touch 3rd?
Are there problems to use i pod touch 3rd as test device as a substitute for iPhone3G?

Comment: Question about testing is `practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession` in http://stackoverflow.com/faq. So please don't close the question or down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can make phone calls and connect to 3G networks and the other can't.  Also, for future reference, 3rd gen will *not* support iOS 6 but the 3GS will (sort of).  Otherwise the specs seem identical.

Comment: Additionally no GPS in the iPod, though it still supports location services through other less accurate means when you have a network connection. I think the cameras might be of different quality than the phone, but not 100% on that. Basically lots of minor technical things, but overall performance should be roughly identical.

Comment: borrrden and @ima, thanks! My app doesn't use network and phone calls. My 3rd gen has no camera.
It's sad that 3rd won't support iOS6. I will not support iOS6 and will wait until iOS7. I hope iOS7 won't support all of non-retina devices.

Comment: I would expect iOS 7 to drop the 3Gs, the only reason 6 will be on the 3Gs (in a more limited form) is because they still sell it so they won't abandon a currently available product line.

Comment: @ima747 thanks, good to know! What do you think about iPad2(which is also non-retina) ?

Comment: That is off topic for this question.

Comment: Discussions are meant for chat rooms, not comment sections.  In fact if you write too many comments, the site will prompt you to move to a chat room.

Comment: iOS 6 is not even out yet so asking about iOS 7 is pointless now.  Nobody can "know" which devices iOS 7 will support when it hasn't even been created yet.